# Login Anonymous User asp.net Core web api

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking for days for the right solution. I am have user name and password stored in my DB.
I want only specific users to get access to some controller methods. How can I implement it, checking by User Id if he has permission or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement basic authentication in web api , adding `[Authorize]` attribute on specific controllers which need provider user's credential . Please refer to below article for code samples :

https://codeburst.io/adding-basic-authentication-to-an-asp-net-core-web-api-project-5439c4cf78ee

https://beetechnical.com/rest-api/how-to-validate-rest-api-using-basic-authentication-in-web-api-net-core/

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/21/aspnet-core-3-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api